# Keyword not supported: 'data source' in entity framework with azure function

Tags: entity-framework, queue, azure-functions, azure-queues

I am using azure function to triggerQueue with entity framework getting 'data source is not supported' error while using entity framework.My connection string is

Following is the code where I am getting error

```
 var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACIGPSDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (var db = new ACIGPSDBConnection(connString))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myQueueItem))
                    {
                        var breadCrumbList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<BreadCrumb>>(myQueueItem);
                        if (breadCrumbList != null && breadCrumbList.Count() > 0)
                        {

                            var activeRouteJob = from j in db.Jobs
                                                 join rj in db.RouteJobs on j.Id equals rj.JobID
                                                 where j.IsActive == true && j.EndDate > DateTime.UtcNow &&
                                                      breadCrumbList.Any(a => a.CarrierId == rj.CarrierID)
                                                 select new RouteJobDelivery
                                                 {
                                                     RouteJobId = rj.Id,
                                                     StartDate = j.StartDate,
                                                     EndDate = j.EndDate
                                                 };
 <add name="ACIGPSDBConnection"
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/ACIGPSDataContext.csdl|res://*/ACIGPSDataContext.ssdl|res://*/ACIGPSDataContext.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; 
         Data source=sqlsrv-scu-dev.database.windows.net;
         initial catalog=md_ACI-dev;user id=;password=;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Tried with the follwing things
1) try with changing providerName from System.Data.EntityClient to System.Data.SqlClient
2) tried removing $quot to single quote
3) tried removing MultipleActiveResultSets=True
4)tried In azure,Select App->Application settings->New connection string->Save

Edit: code image[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF0yT.png)
[CodeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z28M.png)

Comment: Can you show the full exception message and the code where you use the connection string?

Comment: @DavidG :Please see.I added images of this

Comment: No, I'm not going to look at images of error messages and code, if you need help, [edit] the question and add the text here.

Comment: @DavidG code added.Can you please look into it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may still be in the escaping of characters.

If there would be a quote in the connectionString value, as the value itself is enclosed in quotes. The quote in the value will be escaped to ***& quot ;*** .

I suggest you try the following:

1. Try to hardcode this connection string into the code instead of getting it from the configuration file to see if there is any error.
2. If you get a success in step 1, then you get back to get connection string from configuration file. But, you add a output or set a breakpoint before you use it. In this way, you can check if you get the connection string in a right format.
3. If you want to get the connection string from Azure app settings, then replace  **& quot ;** with a " .

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `MultipleActiveResultSets = True` from connection string and it will works.

Comment: Enter connectionstring in appsetting: Select App -> Application Settings -> Enter new Connection String -> Save

Comment: Pretty sure this will not change anything.

Comment: Make sure you also select ‘Custom’ instead of ‘SQL Azure’ for your Entity Framework connection string, even though the database runs on Azure.

Comment: @JoeyCai Yes I made it as Custom type only.Still not working